# Ansible: access json field and use it as variable

Tags: json, ansible

I have to send some PUT requests to a server, at the URL: https://XXXX.com/id, and passing as the body some json files (item1.json, item2.json ...).

```
   - name: invoke service                                            
      uri:
        url: "https://XXXX.com/{{ item.id }}"
        method: PUT
        return_content: yes
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          X-Auth-Token: "XXXXXX"
        body: "{{ lookup('file', item) }}"
      with_items:
        - item1.json
        - item2.json
        - item3.json
```

The id parameter of the url is within the respective json file. The structure of the json files is the following:

```
{
  "address": "163.111.111.111",
  "id": "ajsaljlsaaj",
  "server": "dnnwqkwnlqkwnldkwqldn"
}
```

The code I have written seems not to work, and I get 'ansible.vars.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'id'.
So how can that field been accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the following line:

```
url: "https://XXXX.com/{{ item.id }}"
```

The value of `item` is the JSON **file name** as defined in `with_items`, not the *content* of the JSON file.

---

The **quickest** fix is to open and parse the JSON file the same way you do in your `body:` declaration:

```
- name: invoke service
  uri:
    url: "https://XXXX.com/{{ ( lookup('file', item)|from_json ).id }}"
    method: PUT
    return_content: yes
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      X-Auth-Token: "XXXXXX"
    body: "{{ lookup('file', item) }}"
  with_items:
    - item1.json
    - item2.json
    - item3.json
```

---

One **nicer** solution would be to use the `with_file:` directive instead of `with_items`.

`with_file` would automatically open and read the file content, so no need to call `lookup` anymore:

```
- name: Provision the Docker Swarm managers 
  hosts: localhost
  tags: provision
  gather_facts: False
  become: True
  tasks:
   - name: invoke service
     uri:
       url: "https://XXXX.com/{{ (item|from_json).id }}"
       method: PUT
       return_content: yes
       body_format: json
       headers:
         Content-Type: "application/json"
         X-Auth-Token: "XXXXXX"
       body: "{{ item }}"
     with_file:
      - item1.json
      - item2.json
      - item3.json
```